# Rails adding table and relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got a user table with all my users

Now I want to introduce user-groups

So I need a second table for the groups and a relation between those groups.

It should be possible to set a user in different groups. so I need a n:m relation

It read about that rails can generate most things I need and also generate the migration file? is that true? How does it works?

Migrations

```
class CreateUserGroups < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :user_groups do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :size

      t.timestamps
   end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :user_groups
  end
end


class CreateUserGroupUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :user_group_users do |t|
    t.user_id:integer
    t.user_groups_id:integer
    t.timestamps
  end
end

def self.down
    drop_table :user_group_users
 end

end
```

Comment: if user has many groups, then at the same time groups has many users as well. so it is going to be many to many relation. which includes user model, group model, and interim user_group model.  now for understanding many to many assosiations, read these http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many, http://ryandeussing.com/blog/2013/06/12/nested-associations-and-has-many-through/. hope it will help you

Comment: http://www.gitmatt.com/posts/5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your User and UserGroup model and migration from terminal

```
rails g model User email:string password:string
rails g model UserGroup name:string size:integer
```

You'll also want to create a `UserGroup` and `User` relationship managing table called `UserGroupManager`

```
rails g model UserGroupManager user_id:integer user_group_id:integer
```

Update your database by running this command in terminal

```
rake db:migrate
```

Set up the relationships within app/models/

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_group_managers
  has_many :user_groups, through: :user_group_managers
end

# app/models/user_group.rb
class UserGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_group_managers
  has_many :users, through: :user_group_managers
end

# app/models/user_group_manager.rb
class UserGroupManager < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user_group
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: thanks man the first code was what I'm looking for :) ... thoutght the part in app/models will also be generated automatically

Comment: why have you added this: rails g migration AddColumnUserIdToUser user_id:integer

Comment: and why is in the user.rb only belongs_to and not belongs_to_many`?

Comment: I initially misread your question, then reread it and saw you wanted the UserGroup to contain many Users. So each user needs to belong to a user_group. To do that you need a `user_group_id` column within the user table.

Comment: My current answer will produce the following: UserGroup will have many users. Each User will belong_to one UserGroup

Comment: okay but I need a n:m (many to many) relation, a user should be able to be set in differen groups

Comment: thanks, but I got this error while migrate:

undefined method `user_id'

I add the migrations above

Comment: It might be because you're missing a migration/model for User. I oddly left that out of my answer. Updated my answer to include that.

Comment: Okay Now It works. There were a little typing mistake. For What do I need the size column? is it filled automatically?